# Weird coffeescript code style in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript

I have this line in my coffeescript file

```
if someVariable then no else yes
```

One of the most valuable feature in IDEA for me is code clean up. But it doesn't work as I expect here. After pressing Ctrl+Alt+L, IDEA reformats this line to ugly

```
if someVariable then {
    no
        } else yes
```

Which is not just bad style but error when compile from coffeescript to javascript.

Here is similar line which couldn't be formatted properly by IDEA.

```
return true if someVariable is 5
```

...becomes...

```
{
        return true
        } if someVariable is 5
```

Why is that?

Comment: I tried it out myself and I did not get that behaviour. Are you sure that the file type is correctly registered? Maybe the `.coffee` extension is mapped to be of JavaScript type?

Comment: @maba no, other styles work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug caused by the `if()` statement, `Force braces`: **Always** setting in JavaScript `Wrapping and Braces`.

Issue is [submitted to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7730).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like JavaScript code style. Try checking settings under File>Settings>Project Settings>Code Style.

If you can't manage to set the code style to a correct form, then you still have the option to customize it yourself..

Eventually take a look @ http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/coffeescript-support.html, you might find something interesting if you haven't gone over it all ready. Good luck!